# Nested CASE in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I want to count the total numbers of orders where task is 1 to 3.
Then if entry1 is already counted I need to check if the status is in-progress (all status which are not completed).
I need to use a nested CASE here I don't want to include it in my WHERE clause
because I will join more tables later.

This is my sample table:

```
ID  +    orderid  +  task    +  status
1   |    1        |  1       |  Completed
2   |    2        |  1       |  Saved
3   |    3        |  1       |  Saved
4   |    1        |  2       |  Completed
5   |    1        |  3       |  Completed
```

As you can see in task field which have entry1 the total of in-progress is 2 and completed is 1.
When I execute my query I get results of 2 when I used entry1 and the status is not Saved but I also get the result of 2 when removing the NOT. But when I used ('COMPLETED') I get the right result. So what's the problem with ('SAVED') in my code. I hope I did not mistype anything in my question.

This is my sample query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(
        CASE task
            WHEN 1 THEN task ELSE NULL
        END
        AND
        CASE `status`
            WHEN NOT UPPER('SAVED') THEN `status` ELSE NULL
        END
        ) e1_inprogress
   FROM tableName;
```

For now I just use only task 1 but in my real code I need also to include all task and all status in COUNT.
I think this is simple maybe I missing something then please correct me.
If you have another way please let met know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN task = 1 AND Upper(`status`) = 'SAVED' THEN 1 END
        ) e1_inprogress
   FROM tableName;
```

---

Why it didn't work?

```
WHEN NOT UPPER('SAVED')
```

`NOT UPPER('SAVED')` becomes `NOT (TRUE)` becomes `FALSE`, so you are comparing `CASE Status` against the value `FALSE`.

Your query could have been

```
CASE Upper(`Status`)
WHEN 'SAVED' THEN ... ELSE ...
```

*(nb: swap the code for THEN and ELSE)*

Comment: I get it now.. The problem is my thinking about not equal I should use <> or != instead of NOT or <=>. With your explanation I'll consider this as my accepted answer and with you're code I'll used it instead of mine to shorten my query. Thanks again (I should first study the basic)